# Can not connect and write into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hey everyone as you can see I have placed the whole code because 
I am trying to connect and write information into a database it is very basic and simple but I don't understand what I am doing wrong????
I am trying to let the user place information into the database by filling up a form and after the user gives his information I want to place it in the database. The database itself is build and tables and rows are made.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $phoneErr = $cityErr = $countyErr = $adressErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $phone = $instagram = $facebook = $city = $country = $adress = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
     $phone = "Phone number is required";
   } else {
       $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
     $genderErr = "Gender is required";
   } else {
     $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
<h2>Amsterdam event attending</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>, <">
   Name:
   <input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Adress:
   <input type="text" name="adress" value="<?php echo $adress;?>">
   <span class="error">*</span>
   <br><br>
   City:
   <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city;?>">
   <span class="error">*</span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail:
   <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Instagram:
   <input type="text" name="insta" value="">
   <br><br>
   Facebook:
   <input type="text" name="face" value="">
   <br><br>
   Phone number:
   <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
}
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password =  '1234';
$database = 'amsterdam';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno());        
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijvingen (name, adress, city, email, insta, face, phone, gender);
    VALUES ($_POST[name1], $_POST[adress], $_POST[city], $_POST[email], $_POST[insta], $_POST[face], $_POST[phone], $_POST[gender])";
    mysql_close($conn); 
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does error_log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your VALUES in single quotes. But it's not possible when you write directly your `$_POST` variables in your query because the single quotes around the `$_POST` index names will create errors in your code. The main mistake you're doing is to pass your `$_POST` variables directly into your query which will create serious security issues like SQL injection. 
You should do it with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function and create variables for each index of the $_POST array.

This is how i would do it:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno());        
    }
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name1']);
$adress=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['adress']);
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$insta=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['insta']);
$face=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['face']);
$phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$gender=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);

     $sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijvingen (name, adress, city, email, insta, face, phone, gender);
        VALUES ('$name', '$adress', '$city', '$email', '$insta', '$face', '$phone', '$gender')";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

I didn't review the code before and the code after. I just corrected the query and the values parameter. I also added the `mysqli_query()` function to your code. This function is the main function which is responsible for executing the query which you just missed in your code. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii-    ;0) Thanks

Comment: prego (si, parlo la vostra lingua un po) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Sorry I'm not Italian just living here for a few month.But please don't DV LOL

Comment: *lol* - Oh... I didn't know. Oh well, you'll learn fast enough over there ;-) *lucky dawg* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I hope so. Really nice people here. I love them :-))))

Comment: si, la gente laggiu, è molto gentile! (yes, the people over there are very nice).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to open an I/O stream (stream with the SQL server) AFTER writing something on the page.
You can't open stdout (stream to the page you're generating) and then try to open another stream in php. All other streams need to be generated before you write the first character to the page. Try this:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $phoneErr = $cityErr = $countyErr = $adressErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $phone = $instagram = $facebook = $city = $country = $adress = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
     $phone = "Phone number is required";
   } else {
       $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
     $genderErr = "Gender is required";
   } else {
     $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Amsterdam event attending</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>, <">
   Name:
   <input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Adress:
   <input type="text" name="adress" value="<?php echo $adress;?>">
   <span class="error">*</span>
   <br><br>
   City:
   <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city;?>">
   <span class="error">*</span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail:
   <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Instagram:
   <input type="text" name="insta" value="">
   <br><br>
   Facebook:
   <input type="text" name="face" value="">
   <br><br>
   Phone number:
   <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
}
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password =  '1234';
$database = 'amsterdam';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno());        
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijvingen (name, adress, city, email, insta, face, phone, gender);
    VALUES ($_POST[name1], $_POST[adress], $_POST[city], $_POST[email], $_POST[insta], $_POST[face], $_POST[phone], $_POST[gender])";
    mysql_close($conn); 
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys all what you guys have said is what I was missing I implemented your solutions and it works so far so good!!

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed:

You have an if statement that you aren't using

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
}
```

$sql definition has a semicolon halfway through it, should probably be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijvingen (name, adress, city, email, insta, face, phone, gender)
VALUES ($_POST[name1], $_POST[adress], $_POST[city], $_POST[email], $_POST[insta], $_POST[face], $_POST[phone], $_POST[gender])";
```

After you defined $sql, you never actually queried the database with

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Finally, you have mixed mysql and mysqli. Your close statement should be

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

There are some other concerns as well but it looks as though some of the other answers have already addressed these.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code in your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` curly braces and surround your SQL into `else` braces. Also, seems like you are using `mysql_close()` instead of `mysqli_close()`.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password =  '1234';
$database = 'amsterdam';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno());        
    }else{

    $name=$_POST['name1'];
    $adress=$_POST['adress'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $insta=$_POST['insta'];
    $face=$_POST['face'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijvingen (name, adress, city, email, insta, face, phone, gender)
     VALUES ('$name', '$adress','$city', '$insta, '$face', '$phone', '$gender')";
    mysqli_close($conn); 
    }
}
```

**USE PREPARED STATEMENTS.**

Your code can be easily injected. I would recommend using prepared statements.

In this case your prepared statement would look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijvingen (name, adress, city, email, insta, face, phone, gender)
 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $name, $adress, $city, $email, $insta, $face, $phone, $gender);
 $stmt->close();
 $conn->close();
```